# Script goes into loop

Tags: logitech-gaming-software

I can't solve the problem, when my script goes into infinite loop, and have no idea how to solve it.
I'm using G600 Mouse with LGS, and i want send "9" when mouse button 6  pressed, and send "1" When mouse button 6 released.
The mouse button 6 is also assigned to G-Shift function in LGS

what i've try:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg,family)
if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6 then
PressKey("9")
Sleep(100)
end

if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 6 then
PressKey("1")
Sleep(100)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke both pressing and releasing of keys being simulated.
The most simple way is to use `PressAndReleaseKey("9")` instead of `PressKey("9")`

> The mouse button 6 is also assigned to G-Shift function in LGS

It does not matter.